# Sitemap not generating properly magento

Tags: php, magento, sitemap

I am trying to generate sitemap.xml file for my site using magento backend -

```
Catalog -> Google site map -> Generate
```

In ftp I can see it started generating but after some size it stopped to write content in that file and my site generate URL keep loading and loading. I do not know what is wrong here.